# javascript bootstrap strategy

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

The project I'm working on currently has a single bootstrap file that initialises all the javascript objects within the app. similar to the code below

```
if(document.getElementById('nav')) {
  new navigation();
}

if(document.getElementById('search')) {
 new search();
}

new carousel();
```

However my concern is that for whatever reason one of the lines of JS errors all JS code following will not execute and we're almost creating a single point of failure.

I am interested in hearing alternatives and solutions to this problem and any other bootstrap strategies that may help to alleviate this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your solution depends on whether your app makes sense when some of the components fail to initialise. If any failed components means an app failure, then it makes sense to fail early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/afa65/2/)

For rolling your own, if you can use `data-` html 5 attributes to specify the bootstrap relationships.  Then your bootstrap function can iterate through them and spin up the constructors.

You could also have a mapping object for `id` to constructors.  I'll use that example here.

Assume markup similar to this:

```
<body>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="search"></div>
</body>
```

Define your bootstrap maps, create a bootstrap method, and invoke it:

```
// Declare your bindings in an object
var bootstrapBindings = {
    "navigation" : NavigationBootstrap,
    "search" : SearchBootstrap,
    "failure" : null
};

function bootstrap() {
    var i, element, instance;

    // Bind everything in the bindings
    for(i in bootstrapBindings) {
        if(bootstrapBindings.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            try {
                element = document.getElementById(i);
                if(element) {
                    instance = new bootstrapBindings[i](element);

                    // Nestable bootstrap calls
                    instance.bootstrap();
                }
            } catch(e) {
                // Do something with error if you want
                alert('Unable to bootstrap: ' + e);
            }
        }
    }
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is a chance one of your calls may fail then you should have a solution to catch that error as well. Using a `try` `catch` block would allow you to catch the exceptions and have your code continue.

```
try{
  if(document.getElementById('nav')) {
    new navigation();
  }
}catch(e){
  //handle exception for navigation fail
}

try{
  if(document.getElementById('search')) {
   new search();
  }
}catch(e){
  //handle exception for search fail
}

try{
  new carousel();
}catch(e){
  //handle exception for carousel fail
}
```

Generally you dont want to wrap all your code in try catch blocks, but it sounds like you're fairly confident that some of the code will throw an exception.

Comment: yes this is what I thought but was hoping there was a more graceful option. Regardless of whether or not I think an exception could be thrown I think it is best to pre-empt and guard against such a major failure.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate the init logic inside separate *init* functions, and then have a further function invoke them and capture the results. For example:

```
<body>

<div id=nav></div>
<div id=search></div>

<script>
    function initNavigation() {
        if (document.getElementById('nav')) {
            new navigation();
        }
    }

    function initSearch() {
        if (document.getElementById('search')) {
            new search();
        }
    }

    function initCarousel() {
        new carousel();
    }

    function initNoError() {
        return "ok";
    }

    /**
     * Expects a list of functions to execute, and will capture either the retVal or the error.
     */
    function init() {
        var results = [],
            result;
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            result = {};
            try {
                result.retVal = arguments[i]();
            } catch (e) {
                result.error = e;
            }
            results.push(result);
        }
        return results;
    }

    var initResults = init(initNavigation, initSearch, initCarousel, initNoError);
    console.log(initResults);
</script>

</body>
```

This code will show the following for me. The `ReferenceError` errors are because I don't have your constructor functions. The `TypeError` is seemingly because Firefox is returning the `<div>` of the same id, and this div is of course not a constructor function.

```
[
    Object { error=ReferenceError: navigation is not defined},
    Object { error=TypeError: search is not a constructor},
    Object { error=ReferenceError: carousel is not defined},
    Object { retVal="ok"}
]
```

Comment: Self-closing `div`s combined with `script` without `type` attribute?  You just want to watch the world burn, don't you?